# Visual Studio and IIS manager

Tags: visual-studio, iis

forgive my dumb question, but I have a new project solution in my Visual Studio 2017.  Is there anything I need to do on my local IIS Manager as far as Default Websites, in order to run that solution in VS locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio 2013, 2015 and 2017 use IIS Express by default, which runs with its own separate `applicationHost.config` file and shares no configuration with the "real" IIS, this also means that you cannot use IIS Manager to configure IIS Express.

If you do configure IIS to use your "Local IIS Web Server" instead of IIS Express then you will need to run Visual Studio elevated ("As Administrator") to give it permission to reconfigure your local IIS. I do not know how Visual Studio decides which IIS Website to add your application-binding to - I cannot find any information about this. I guess you'll have to experiment.

Note that using Local IIS means that the project may not be portable to other machines - so if you're working on a team and your coworkers have different IIS configurations then you'll be in a mess. You should always prefer IIS Express where possible.